# Filter by name (in a specific column) failed for specific names

Tags: r, dplyr

In the dataframe described below, I can filter (by name) for "Signal transduction mechanisms" but I cannot filter for "ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]" (I get a dataframe with empty rows).

`test_2 <- filter(DF, grepl("ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]", DF$C))`
`test_1 <- filter(DF, grepl("Signal transduction mechanisms", DF$C))`

```
DF
       B     C
# 1    1    ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]
# 2    2    ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]
# 3    2    Signal transduction mechanisms
# 4    5    Signal transduction mechanisms
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `fixed = TRUE` to `grepl`:

`fixed = TRUE`: use exact matching.

```
test_2 <- filter(df, grepl("ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]", fixed = TRUE, df$C))
```

OR
We could use `%in%` Operator:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(C %in% "ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]")
```

```
  B                               C
1 1 ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]
2 2 ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]
```

Comment: It works with ```test_2 <- filter(df, grepl("ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]", fixed = TRUE, df$C))``` but it does not with 
```df %>% filter(C %in% "ABC transporters [PATH:ko02010]")```

Comment: @Daniele `fixed = TRUE` doesn't mean it should match the whole string.  `%in%` is looking for an exact match of the whole string, whereas `grepl` can be a substring match i.e. if your string have some leading/lagging spaces, `%in%` wouldn't return that as TRUE

Comment: Thank you akrun was busy with this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972187/complex-join-between-two-dataframes/71972677#71972677>

Comment: @Daniele have you loaded `dplyr`?

Comment: Yes, I did load the dyplr